# SQL Query to count by time for particular column

Tags: sql, sql-server

OK I'm using MS SQL and I have a table with values like this:

```
ID     Date     Radio     Time
111    4/1/09    1        3:00:00
111    4/1/09    2        4:00:00
111    4/1/09    3       14:00:00
111    4/1/09    1       15:00:00
111    4/1/09    3       16:00:00
222    4/1/09    2        2:00:00
222    4/1/09    1        5:00:00
222    4/1/09    1       19:00:00
333    4/1/09    1        3:00:00
333    4/1/09    2        5:00:00
333    4/1/09    2        13:00:00
333    4/1/09    3        17:00:00
```

Ok so I need a Query where:

```
window 1 < 12:00
13 < window 2 < 15:00
window 3 > 16:00
```

To return sums:

```
           Window1     Window2    Window3  
Radio 1:     3           0          2
Radio 2:     3           1          0
Radio 3:     0           1          2
```

I have tried using count() but I cannot get these to join correctly on the right 'radio'
Any suggestions?

Comment: This cannot be solved without knowing what DBMS you're using (Mysql, MSSql, postgres, oracle, sqlite - just to name a few)

Comment: Funny - people always forget to tell us the name of their table.

Comment: Also, do you mean 'Window 1 < 12:00'?  If so, what about the gap 12:00-13:00?  And 15:00 to 16:00?  If not, what about the gap 00:00 to 12:00?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
SELECT [Radio],
    SUM(CASE WHEN [Time] < 12 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Window1,
    SUM(CASE WHEN [Time] >= 12 AND [TIME] < 15 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Window2,
    SUM(CASE WHEN [Time] >= 16 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Window3
FROM [Table]
GROUP BY [Radio]
```

Adjust <= / < and >= / > as appropriate; you weren't very specific on that point.

Also, your first condition was `window 1 > 12`.  I'm assuming you mean `window 1 < 12`.

Answer (score 3):

I may have cheated and used SQL Server 2008 using a [time(7)] datatype for the time column, which I called "thetime."  This will give you the same results as you have asked for.

```
select radio, SUM(case when thetime <= '12:00:00' then 1 else 0 end) Window1
    , SUM(case when thetime between '13:00:00' and '15:59:59' then 1 else 0 end) Window2
    , SUM(case when thetime >= '15:00:00' then 1 else 0 end) Window3
from stackoverflow
GROUP BY radio
ORDER BY radio
```

Hope that helps,

Calvin